# angular material mat-drawer issue with height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

For some reason, I can't seem to get the mat drawer to occupy the remaining available height on the screen. I've tried:

```
.drawer-container {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

But I still get an overflow for some reason even though there's only one element on screen as indicated by the scroll bar:

[image]

And when I remove the CSS rules, I end up with this:

[image]

Basically about 10% of the screen height only. I've considered using a fixed height, but I'm guessing it would look cut off if viewed on a larger or smaller monitor. I'd appreciate any help as I'm really not familiar with the full properties of angular material and how to properly manipulate them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us html code in drawer. Seems like you need create styling for drawer itself not his container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case any dropped by this and had a similar problem.
i fixed this long ago by applying

```
.drawer-container {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

just make sure the parent has a `position: relative`

Answer (score -1):

Percentage based width/height is not yet supported by mat-sidenav i suppose.

try `height: 100vh;` instead.

that should work, but will add a scrollbar if there is any toolbar in your page.

**UPDATE:**

HTML:

```
<mat-drawer-container class="parent" autosize>
        <mat-drawer mode="side">
            Your sidenav content
        </mat-drawer>

        <div class="content">
            Your main content.
        </div>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;   // calc(100vh - 64px) can be used if there is navbar at the top
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
}
```